How do I linkify text in an NSTextView using TextKit 2?
I'd like to linkify text in an NSTextView. I know about the isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled property, but that is only for text typed in. If I programmatically set the string or paste in text, it won't be linkified.
I tried using the NSTextContentStorageDelegate:
func textContentStorage(_ textContentStorage: NSTextContentStorage,
                        textParagraphWith range: NSRange) -> NSTextParagraph? {

    let text = textContentStorage.textStorage!.attributedSubstring(from: range)
    let styledText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: text)
    let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: range.length)
    let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    var didAddAttributes = false
        
    detector.enumerateMatches(in: text.string, options: [], range: textRange) {
        (match, _, _) in
        if let url = match?.url, let urlRange = match?.range {
            styledText.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: urlRange)
            didAddAttributes = true
        }
    }

    if didAddAttributes {
        return NSTextParagraph(attributedString: styledText)
    }

    return nil;
}

This code successfully styles the links (underlined, blue foreground color), but the cursor is still the I-beam, not the pointing hand, and clicking the links does nothing. It's only rendering like a link.
How do I get proper clickable links using TextKit 2?
FWIW, this is Xcode 16, macOS Sonoma 14.6.1.
Edit: Per @Willeke's comment, I should have mentioned that as a fallback, I'm currently using checkTextInDocument(). It works, but is very inefficient as it checks the whole document on each change. The delegate method I posted above is only called on the paragraphs that change. I'd like something more efficient like that. The pitch for TextKit 2 is that it's fast. I'd like to know how to do this the "TextKit2 way" but I can't seem to find documentation on how.

Maybe this still works: Automatic Link Detection not working in NSTextView after programmatically setting text

@Willeke It does still work and that is what I'm doing now. However, that method processes the whole document each time. The code I posted just affects paragraphs that have changed.

How about checkText(in:types:options:)?

I tried that, passing NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue for types, but it didn't do anything.
